# how to put an URL as a parameter in another URL for successful parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, query-string

say I want to set the URL: `www.a.com?str1=12&str2=67` as a parameter in another URL so that it can be parsed properly.

**problem**:
say i set it as a parameter in another url as-

```
www.a.com?redirect_to=www.a.com?str1=12&str2=67
```

then what happens is when I parse the url then I get the value of **`redirect_to`** as **`www.a.com?str1=12`** because **`strt2`** is considered to be another parameter. so what can I do to get **`www.a.com?str1=12&str2=67`** as the value of **`redirect_to`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the redirect url with CGI.escape:

```
require 'cgi'
my_url = "www.a.com?redirect_to=#{CGI.escape('www.a.com?str1=12&str2=67')}"
# my_url => "www.a.com?redirect_to=www.a.com%3Fstr1%3D12%26str2%3D67"
```